# NSNumber to float error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am not sure why I am getting the following error:
[image]

the height doesn't complain anything, it's just the width... why?

Here's my code:

```
@interface Embed : RKObject {
    NSString * _url;
    NSString * _original;
    NSNumber * _width;
    NSNumber * _height;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * url;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * original;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * width;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * height;

@end

@implementation Embed
@synthesize url = _url;
@synthesize original = _original;
@synthesize width = _width;
@synthesize height = _height;

+ (NSDictionary*) elementToPropertyMappings {
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithKeysAndObjects:
            @"url", @"url",
            @"original", @"original",
            @"width", @"width",
            @"height", @"height",
            nil]; 

}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_url release];
    [_original release];
    [_width release];
    [_height release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

not sure why it's a CGFloat, never convert it to CGFloat anywhere else

Comment: would it not have actually been better if not easier to copy and paste the code rather than put a tiny,tiny screen shot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message would imply that it thinks the 'width' message, as posted to the `objectAtIndex:0` returns a `CGFloat`, not an `NSNumber`.

It's possible it has made an incorrect guess about the thing you're calling width on, so assuming you have your object defined correctly you probably just need to give the compiler the correct hint, e.g. (broken down to make it clear where the cast goes):

```
[
    [
        (MyCorrectType *)[
                             [
                                 [postsObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                             embeds]
                         objectAtIndex:0] // cast goes with the result of this
    width]
floatValue]
```

Comment: yes this solves the issue... the first time I ever encountered such thing.. is the compiler not as smart as I think?

Comment: @adit, `objectAtIndex:` returns an `id`. So the compiler can't determine the object's class at compile time. It looked through all the included classes for a width method, and probably found UIBarButtonItem's width method first -- which returns a CGFloat. This issue doesn't come up often, but it happens occasionally (it's not a prob if both methods return some sort of object, only if there is a conflict with a native type). You could always rename your methods.

Answer (score 0):

The barely discernable error leads me to think that your -width method is returning a CGFloat rather than an NSNumber*.